# You do not have any linked accounts with 200+ rep in flair

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, flair

With reference to this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315076/2451726), I viewed the [user's profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3320161/anand-singh). In the page user flair showing different warning, that I never see anywhere in the Stack Exchange.

Since the user already earned 1.9k reputation in Stack Overflow, but the flair shows no account with 200+ rep.

Is it due to the wrong network profile is linked in the flair?

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Flair]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the image URL isn't valid / it doesn't go to an actual profile that even exists. I frankly don't know where that URL came from, and I'm not going to really try and figure it out, but if you use their actual Stack Exchange user ID, you get the correct image:

[image: Actual User ID]

Comment: A merge probably?