# My network profile flair keeps showing that I don't have any linked accounts with 200+rep

Tags: support, linked-accounts, flair, combined-flair, hidden-communities

A few months ago I discovered that my network profile flair had stopped appearing as before, and instead it was showing that I don't have any linked accounts with 200+rep.

Like this question:
[You do not have any linked accounts with 200+ rep in flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273375/you-do-not-have-any-linked-accounts-with-200-rep-in-flair)

I did search for a while to find a solution at that time with no success. Then I thought that it could be something temporary.

But today some months later, the flair is still not displaying correctly.
I am going rounds around, logging-in/out but nothing changes... and I can't find anywhere the answer.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/248161/ffrewin?tab=profile

Is there any problem with the network flair? Is it something I did wrong? How to fix this?

This is not a duplicate with that other question:

1. that answer doesn't address my issue.
2. My question actually proved to be a how to do something on SE that I didn't know and couldn't find the answer, rather than reporting a bug on a feature.

Comment: Actually combined flair *wasn't* showing hidden accounts.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek duplicate is a bug report about when it did, and [the answer over there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291537/165773) explains that this bug was fixed and hidden accounts shouldn't appear in combined flair anymore

Comment: @gnat - in my case I was unaware of the hidden accounts feature and how it could affect the flair. I didn't even remember myself using the feature to hide accounts. So although that other question may be connected somehow, it is actually a different question in nature and scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You hid some of your accounts. You can unhide them using this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/hidecommunities/current

After unhiding, you may need to wait 24-36 hours before the flair updates. Then the sites you unhid (and have 200+ rep) should now show up on the flair.

Comment: thanks for the link. That's weird though, as I can't recall myself hiding those accounts.

Comment: @FFrewin Did you now intentionally hide the accounts with less than 200 rep? That is not necessary for the flair to function, although it is not a problem of course.

Comment: Yes - it's now intentionaly

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you have none (at least from a regular user's point of view)

[image]

I guess that hidden accounts are *not* going to show up, and all your visible accounts are under 200 reputation. I can see a bunch of accounts with >200 reputation with my moderator account.

Try making some of your higher reputation accounts visible and they should turn up on your combined flare.

Comment: thanks for your answer. That's weird though, as I can't recall myself hiding those accounts - but likely I pressed that button and forgot about it...

Comment: I ll accept the other answer - as the link to hide communities was the key for me here. I was totally ignoring/overlooking that inside my account. Thanks a lot!